# Any difference?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have 2 pieces of code written using tensorflow.
One is this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
      if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.99):
        print("\nReached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!")
      self.model.stop_training = True

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

callbacks = myCallback()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[callbacks])
```

The other one is this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def train_mnist():

    class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            if(logs.get('accuracy')>99):
                print("\n Se incheie antrenamentul")
                self.model.stop_training = True

    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

    callbacks = myCallback()

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    # model fitting
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, callbacks=[callbacks])
    
    # model fitting
    return history.epoch, history.history['acc'][-1]

train_mnist()
```

The first one gives an accuracy of 0.99 after 3 or 4 epochs. The second one gives an accuracy of 0.91 after 10 epochs. Why? They both look the same to me. Any ideas?

Comment: They both are same. The outputs maybe different everytime you run them due to stochasticity

Answer (score 1):

They both are almost identical. I have just checked both accuracy. The only reason why your accuracy is showing different is because in 2nd code you have returned

```py
history.history['acc'][-1]
```

instead of

```py
history.history['accuracy'][-1]
```

Also you need to save the history of 1st code for comparision like this:

```py
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, callbacks=[callbacks])
```

Also figured out that you have stopped model training outside of if condition in 1st code.

```py
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
      if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.99):
        print("\nReached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!")
      self.model.stop_training = True
```

It should be like this:

```py
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
      if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.99):
        print("\nReached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!")
        self.model.stop_training = True
```

Both code must be giving around 0.99% accuracy.

Since your 2nd code is not showing the exact accuracy. I am posting the whole modified code for your 2nd code

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from os import path, getcwd, chdir

path = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/mnist.npz"

def train_mnist():

    class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            if(logs.get('accuracy')>99):
                print("\n Se incheie antrenamentul")
                self.model.stop_training = True

    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist


    

    (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()



    x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
    

    callbacks = myCallback()
 

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
 
    

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    # model fitting
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, callbacks=[callbacks])
    
    # model fitting
    return history.epoch, history.history['accuracy'][-1]

train_mnist()
```

Comment: Since you have re-run the code, please post the exact results returned by the two different methods (from your post it is not clear hat they are indeed different).

Comment: Sooo.. How do I get my second code to also show 99% accuracy? Tried modifying to 'accuracy' instead of 'acc', did nothing.

Comment: See my updated post. You have stopped the model training outside if loop in 1st code

Comment: Did the modification. Still doesn't do anything. The problem is in the second code. That is the code I want to go to 99%.

Comment: Hi, I have again updated the post writing the full code for ur 2nd code. Check the accuracy in google colab itself.

Comment: Yeah, now it works. But I still can't see what you modified. Looks the same to me...

Comment: As you can see from OP's comment, reposting a whole bunch of code where you have modified 1 or 2 things (without explicitly indicate them) is hardly helpful. Please do so explicitly and/or by comments in the code (also, updating the answer with edit after edit after edit is not helpful either).

Comment: In any case, you doesn't seem to have changed anything apart from `history['acc']` -> `history['accuracy']` (hopefully now you see the reason for my 1st comment above).

Comment: Well... Apparently the callback structure with the end_epoch call is no longer supported by tensorflow 2. Something like that, found it on a page. Otherwise, it works well, except for the fact that it doesn't stop when reaching 99%. Thx alot.